# Add simple test method to TestSuite

Tags: python, unit-testing, test-suite

How can I add simple test method from `unittest.TestCase` to `TestSuite`. As I see it is only possible to add whole class only to suite, for example I want something like this:

```
import unittest


class MyBaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.abs = "test"


class MyTestClass(MyBaseTestCase):
    def test_abs(self):
        if self.abs:
            pass


class MyTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addTest(MyTestClass.test_abs)
```

Here I get an error: `AttributeError: 'TeamcityTestResult' object has no attribute 'abs'`. It seems like it runs as a test, but `setUpClass` does not calls.

Comment: Can you post your MyTestClass code ?

Comment: Yes, did add full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you run the test suite? I used your code and ran it using 'python3 -m unittest test.py':

```
import unittest


class MyBaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.abs = "test"


class MyTestClass(MyBaseTestCase):
    def test_abs(self):
        if self.abs:
            pass


class MyTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addTest(MyTestClass.test_abs)
```

And it works.

Comment: Thank you for point. I use IntelljIdea for run it. And configure run it as module and choose test.MyTestSuite there, which makes command like this: `python.exe C:\Users\Me\.IntelliJIdea2018.3\config\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py --target test.MyTestSuite` that call python with `python -m unittest test.MyTestSuite`. If I choose whole file with testSuite with command `python -m unittest test.py` it starts work.